# Proper Use of TO_DATE FUNCTION

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I would like to use the TO_DATE function in one of my stored procedures.  However, I am unsure which type of values I can put into the TO_DATE function.  For example, would it be acceptable if I did the following: TO_DATE('MAR', 2012)?

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL Developer, and the DBMS is Oracle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, I am unsure which type of values I can put into the TO_DATE function

When you have such question you typically want to consult with the documentation [TO_DATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions203.htm#SQLRF06132)

> `TO_DATE(char [, fmt [, 'nlsparam' ] ])`

All possible format models (`fmt`) are described in [Format Models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210)

> would it be acceptable if I did the following: TO_DATE('MAR', 2012)

No, it wouldn't. But you can do

```
SELECT TO_DATE('MAR 2012', 'MON YYYY') dt FROM dual;
```

Output:

```
|                           DT |
|------------------------------|
| March, 01 2012 00:00:00+0000 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/24695)** demo

Answer (score 1):

The format of Oracle `TO_DATE` function is `TO_DATE('string you need to convert', 'format', 'optional nls parameter')`

So, you can go like this `SELECT TO_DATE('04-02-14 10:12', 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI') FROM DUAL;`

[More info](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)

Answer (score 0):

Please Read following pages it have complete detail what you can do, should not do

Although it applies to Oracle Database 11g but most of it is true for others.

**TO_DATE** Function reference:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions203.htm#SQLRF06132

**TO_DATE** format models: 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#i34924

GENERAL DATATYPE CONVERSION RULES
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements002.htm#i55214